# how to take jsp textbox value to java class file?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

Hello i use jsp file and i write following code in jsp file.

```
 <aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%= updateTestiURL.toString() %>"  
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <aui:input name="subject" label="Subject"/>
  <aui:input type="file" name="fileName"/>
```

using this i can upload file successfully with my java file. but when i try to get text box value it returns null.
i write following code in java to get text box.

```
    subject=(String)actionRequest.getParameter("subject");
```

If i remove following

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

from jsp file then i can get value of text box, but another problem generate.I cant upload file. Kindly tell me how to get both ?

Comment: `request.getParameter()` does not work with multipart requests.
Each upload library has its own methods for retrieving form parameters.

Comment: What library you are using?

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: What library are you using? What are those tags `aui`?

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionRequest"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.ActionResponse" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<%@ page import="com.testi.slayer.service.TestimonialLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.testi.slayer.model.Testimonial" %>
<%@ page import="com.testi.slayer.service.TestimonialTempLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.testi.slayer.model.TestimonialTemp" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `enctype` is `multipart/form-data`, the request needs to be parsed as a multipart request. There are several libraries available for that task, e.g. [Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Comment: A good start would be to [search for some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=commons+file+upload+example)

Comment: kindly tell me solution please. how to get textbox data in java file and how to upload file also